# How to restart computer without pressing 'reset button'

Tags: linux, bash, reboot

Maybe a bash command or something?

Comment: Please add your OS, even though everyone already assumes it's Linux

Comment: BTW: is there any reason you need a reset if you can simply use the normal shutdown options? Reset is only required if your computer is stuck or you lack GUI options to perform the action

Comment: make sure, if you're on a remote system, u shut down the right machine :) always double check ur on the right machine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Different versions of linux have different commands to shutdown and reboot the computer. Either provide the OS and distribution you're using, or try these commands:

- shutdown -r now
- init 6
- reboot

If you want to only power it down, use:

- shutdown -h now
- halt
- poweroff
- init 0

Both sets of commands typically need sudo permission to execute.

Comment: It's init 6 for a reboot.

Comment: @Dave Thanks. I compiled the whole answer under the assumption user wanted to halt the machine. You're right, it's init 6 for reboot and init 0 for halt.

Comment: I typically use reboot and halt -p (halt and power off)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are asking about a "bash command or something", I assume that you are on Linux or something. Try this:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

This will restart the machine.

Comment: On some distros you need SU privileges in order to execute this command. So if this won't work for you try putting sudo at the front of shutdown -r now.

Comment: Never personally seen a distro that didn't require superuser for this. I have always needed to use sudo.

Comment: Good point. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I envision some newbisch Linux user (oxymoron but hey!) trying this out... It's like telling your grandma to use Alt+F4 to shutdown her programs ^^

Comment: When my grandma asks me for a key combination to shutdown a program, what else could I possibly tell her?

Comment: And by the by: when I was a newbish Linux user, there was no other option.

Comment: Some Unix systems do not require root privileges to shutdown a machine locally.  The rationale being that a user with physical access to the big red button will use it if other methods are not available.  I think this is wise.  I have an Ubuntu VM from a default install.  It requires root to use *shutdown*, but allows me to turn the machine via *Gnome* without root.  Same thing with OpenSolaris.  This seems odd.

Comment: For the record, no need to prefix with `sudo` if you're already logged in to the terminal as root.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Magic SysRq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) enabled in your kernel, you can use alt+printscreen+(char) even if your system is relatively broken. (for example, if X is hosed)

Don't use this approach unless you can't do a normal shutdown -- shutdown -r now or similar is far better if you actually have a usable command line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you run the bash on some Unix environment, you should have shutdown command, which has "-r" option for rebooting.

Manuals for this can be found by issuing "man shutdown" command, or by checking [this page for BSD](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/shutdown/) or [this page for Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/8/shutdown) versions of the shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on any blank space of windows desktop -> New -> Shortcut. A “Create Shortcut” window will open.

In the blank, type in:
**shutdown.exe -r -t 0**
Click “Next” button for next step.
Type in whatever name you like in the blank. I use “Restart”.
Then, click “Finish” button.
You can also set “Shortcut key” in the shutdown shortcut’s propertise to shutdown computer using keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

For SysV style: shutdown -g0 -y -i6

For BSD style: shutdown -r now

Answer (score 0):

Two sequential `CTRL+ALT+DEL` commands will reset Windows* machines.

<sup>* I haven't used this since XP...</sup>

Comment: not anymore, not for a while

Comment: did even XP allow this? I thought it went out when NT came along.

Comment: I have occasion to use it on XP machines around here.  Still works.

Comment: This doesn't work on XP.